# Do Ingresses create LoadBalancer services behind the scenes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When you create an Ingress on a managed Kubernetes cluster like GKE, does it automatically create a Load Balancer service in Kubernetes that sits in front of it?

So, for example, if I create an Ingress like this on GKE, would I need to also provision a Load Balancer service in Kubernetes for this Ingress to be exposed to the public internet? Or does the Ingress create the Load Balancer service for me automatically? Or, does the Ingress not even create a Load Balancer Kubernetes service itself, and just provisions a GCP application load balancer directly?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mcu-all
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mcu.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: path1
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /path2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: path2
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: Yes, it does, it creates a LoadBalancer with a public ip for the cluster, all to redirect traffic from the outside world-> the cluster-> the service that is running the nginx controller. And once the controller receives the traffic, based on the rules that you create, redirect the traffic to other services-pods

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome 

Answer (score 0):

Per GKE official docs:

> When you specify kind: Ingress in a resource manifest, you instruct
> GKE to create an Ingress resource. By including annotations and
> supporting workloads and Services, you can create a custom Ingress
> controller. Otherwise, GKE makes appropriate Google Cloud API calls to
> create an external Application Load Balancer

**UPDATE**:

As stated above, classics http(s)  Load balancer is created containing the services path1 and path2.
Also an external ephemeral global IP are created (no region) (keep refreshing until set) for the ingress.

Lastly double check under Services & ingress the ingress type defaulted to External http(s) LB and frontends ip.

Comment: I'm unsure how to interpret this text block. Is it saying "If you use GKE's built-in Ingress controller, you'll get an external Application Load Balancer, but if you use a custom Ingress controller, you won't."? When GKE does create an external Application Load Balancer, does it also create a Load Balancer Service in Kubernetes?

Comment: what are the Services type ? I guess they are set to LoadBalancer

Comment: Which Services type? The Ingress is pointing to two ClusterIP Services. I'm asking if the Ingress itself creates a LoadBalancer Service when provisioning a GCP application load balancer.

Comment: i have updated, thank you